# DevExpress Gridview can't edit time in DateTime

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a DateTime column, and when I try to edit it only the date is displayed, not the date & time. I have set a mask for the display to show the Date & Time for Display.

I've also tried a few code samples that from what I can understand should make the time appear with the date when editing, but alas they do not.

How can I make it so that I can edit both the date & time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a date in-place repository, and set the edit format to a "g"

Attached a sample screenshot from the properties window.[image]